# Transaction at application level

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net main desktop application and there are also supporting applications of the main application.
I want if any kind of exception occur at any point of time then the whole application will shutdown but rollback all transactions first. No data should be lost.
Is there any way out for this. I don't want to use transaction in every method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below linkprovide the details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973833.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand your logic beyond the database scope, you should use a design pattern. For example if you want to have an action doing things on the file system and two databases in the same time, all in the same "transaction", then you have to use a broader "transaction" sense. Then you could rollback the whole "transaction", including the work done in both databases and the file system. This concept is the so called **"Unit of Work"**.

Just to be clear, this is not automatically done. It is not like a transaction handled by the SQL Server or any other DBMS. In order to implement such logic, I would suggest to use the [Unit of Work design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx).

Hope I helped!